# Re-arranging an array recursively in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Please I have an array of data arranged in this format

```
[ 
   (int) 0 => [
    'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/001',
    'AF101' => (float) 56,
    'AF102' => (float) 46,
],
```

but I need a function that can read the array and rearrange it to appear in the format

```
[
(int) 0 => [
 'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/001',
 'course_id' => 'AF101',
 'total' => '56',
 ],
(int) 1 => [
'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/001',
'course_id' => 'AF102',
'total' => '46',
],
]
```

In the second array which is derived from the first array, the

```
'AF101' => '56'
```

is interchanged to

```
'course_id' => 'AF101',
'total' => '56'
```

Any contributions and suggestions are welcome

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `foreach()` within `array_walk()` to get that done as shown below.

Test: [here](https://eval.in/622014).

```
<?php

    $arr    = [
            [
                'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/001',
                'AF101' => (float) 56,
                'AF102' => (float) 46,
            ],
            [
                'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/003',
                'AF101' => (float) 76,
                'AF102' => (float) 39,
            ],
    ];

    function filterResult($arr, $result=[]){
        $walk = array_walk($arr, function($data) use(&$result){
            if(is_array($data)){
                foreach($data as $key=>$item){
                    if(preg_match("#(^[A-Z]*?)(\d)#", $key)){
                        $result[] = [
                            'student_id'    =>$data['student_id'],
                            'course_id'     => $key,
                            'total'         => $data[$key],
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return $result;
    }
    var_dump(filterResult($arr));
```

The `var_dump() above produces:`

```
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'student_id' => string 'AF/2016/SCH/001' (length=15)
          'course_id' => string 'AF101' (length=5)
          'total' => float 56
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'student_id' => string 'AF/2016/SCH/001' (length=15)
          'course_id' => string 'AF102' (length=5)
          'total' => float 46
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'student_id' => string 'AF/2016/SCH/003' (length=15)
          'course_id' => string 'AF101' (length=5)
          'total' => float 76
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          'student_id' => string 'AF/2016/SCH/003' (length=15)
          'course_id' => string 'AF102' (length=5)
          'total' => float 39
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Poiz that worked like magic

Comment: @user3792206  Well, then mark it as the right answer....

Comment: @Poiz why do you use hashtags (#) first and last in the regular expression pattern, I can't seem to find why anywhere, since the keys don't contain hashtags. Using live regex php testers it doesn't match but running the code does the magic. Anyhow, good job, your answer is far better than mine!

Comment: @user3792206   To use `Regex` Pattern(s) within `preg_match()` You need a **Delimiter** at the start and end of your Pattern(s). The Hash-Tag is a delimiter, which merely informs PHP where our Regex starts and ends. Any other Unique token like **/**, **&**, **%**, etc could also have been used. The Regex just says: *Match as fewer characters starting with Letters A through Z as possible... right after the A to Z comes digits....* The Idea here is that since the `Course IDs` will always be like **AF101**  or **BCF480**; we can use this regex to find the Course ID effectively.

Comment: @user3792206    The L-I-V-E Regex Tester would most likely misinterpret the version with "Hash-Tags", however if you remove both hash-tags (which as already explained are delimiters) and try to run it on the Regex Tester, it works again: try `(^[A-Z]*?)(\d)` in the Tester...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Poiz , I honestly didn't know there are other delimiters than **/**

Answer (score 0):

This code works for your problem, assuming that there is nothing else in each student sub-array than the id and courses with scores:

```
$original_array = [
    0 => [
        'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/001',
        'AF101' => 56,
        'AF102' => 46,
    ],
    1 => [
        'student_id' => 'AF/2016/SCH/002',
        'AF101' => 76,
        'AF102' => 39,
    ],
];
$newarray = [];

foreach ($original_array as $student)
{
    $student_id = $student['student_id'];
    unset($student['student_id']);
    foreach ($student as $course_id => $score)
    {
        $newarray[count($newarray)] = $newarray[count($newarray)] = [
            'student_id' => $student_id,
            'course_id' => $course_id,
            'total' => $score,
        ];

    }
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newarray);
```

Comment: thanks alot for your response. Am very grateful

Comment: As @Poiz answer is more elaborative, you should consider marking it as the correct answer